# Wso2 IS SMS OTP returns 401 page after login

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Wso2 IS 5.10.0 I have configured basic auth and sms otp. I wanted to trigger basic auth using url like below without login page(skipping login page with authentication at backend with the username and password provided).

https://192.168.1.10:9448/oauth2/authorize?client_id=USER_PORTAL&code_challenge=KmuKeL_V3Gc5rRp9zEQeK0SFMrHZU25lLyrtnr8uekE&code_challenge_method=S256&commonAuthCallerPath=/oauth2/authorize&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https://192.168.1.10:9448/user-portal/login&response_type=code&scope=internal_login+internal_humantask_view+openid&relyingParty=USER_PORTAL&type=oidc&sp=User+Portal&isSaaSApp=false&username=test&password=test@123

The login is successful but after that smsotp page is throwing 401 error even after authentication. But same thing is working if I am login with login page(mobile sms otp page will be shown successfully). I am not getting what is wrong.

EDIT:
After login it is routing to sms otp page like below.

https://192.168.1.10:9448/oauth2/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/smsotp.jsp?client_id=USER_PORTAL&code_challenge=KmuKeL_V3Gc5rRp9zEQeK0SFMrHZU25lLyrtnr8uekE&code_challenge_method=S256&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize&forceAuth=false&isSaaSApp=false&passiveAuth=false&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.10%3A9448%2Fuser-portal%2Flogin&response_type=code&scope=internal_login+internal_humantask_view+openid&sp=User+Portal&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=c23b62da-3031-44fd-892c-5cff2e62db58&relyingParty=USER_PORTAL&type=oidc&sp=User+Portal&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=SMSOTP

Comment: Do you redirect to `https://<host>:<port>/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/mobile.jsp?....` page in the working scenario and do you redirected to `https://<host>:<port>/oauth2/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/mobile.jsp?...` in the Basic Auth Request Path Authentication to show 401 error?

Comment: I experienced the above-mentioned behavior and the `oauth2` part in the path is not removed in the erroneous flow

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna Is there any wokraround actually I have written a custom authenticator which takes username and does authentication based on username and prompts mobile sms otp page. So, I was using login directly with custom authenticator using the url like above. But after authentication successfull it was throwing 401 error once it routes to mobile sms otp page. So, I tried using basic authenticator with user name and password to skip login page but it thrown after routinh to mobilt sms otp page.

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I have updated the url in the question. It is adding oauth2 in the request url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This invalid URL (/oauth2/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/..) is generated due to relative URLs configured for the following properties (in deployment.toml). To address it, you can update them with a slash at the beginning as below.

```
[authentication.authenticator.sms_otp.parameters]
SMSOTPAuthenticationEndpointURL= "/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/smsotp.jsp"
SMSOTPAuthenticationEndpointErrorPage= "/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/smsotpError.jsp"
MobileNumberRegPage = "/smsotpauthenticationendpoint/mobile.jsp"
```